# SQL query to the required output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a desired output as below out of two input tables
`order` table`users` table

```
id  order_date        id    username
1   2019-01-01        1 A
2   2019-01-01        2 B
3   2019-01-02        3 B
4   2019-01-03        4 A
5   2019-01-03        5 B
```

Desired Output

```
order_date  username    orders
2019-01-01  A          1
2019-01-02  A          0
2019-01-03  A          1
```

I tried with this query,

```
SELECT o. order_date as order_date, u.username as username,
       ISNULL (COUNT (username),0) AS orders
FROM Order O LEFT JOIN users U ON o.id=u.id
WHERE   u.username = ‘A’
GROUP BY o. order_date, u.username
ORDER BY o. order_date, u.username
```

Which give me this result

```
order_date  username    orders
  
2019-01-01  A          1
2019-01-03  A          1
```

I don't know how to bring this part in the result "2019-01-02   A       0"

could anyone please help me with the query, Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: `...ON o.id=u.id
AND   u.username = 'A'...`

Comment: order_date username orders
2019-01-01 NULL 0
2019-01-01 A          1
2019-01-02 NULL 0
2019-01-03 NULL 0
2019-01-03 A          1

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I give the same output as previous

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag a single database only.

Comment: MS SQL Server... removed the other tag

Comment: "I don't know how to bring this part in the result "2019-01-02 A 0""   Why?  The date `2019-01-02` has id=3, and id=3 in the users table refers to user=`B` ...

Comment: @TheImpaler query didn't work either

Comment: @Luuk that's why 2019-01-02 date should show A as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select d.order_date, 'A' as username, coalesce(cnt, 0) as orders
from (select distinct order_date as order_date from orders) d
left join (
  select o.order_date, count(*) as cnt
  from orders o 
  join users u on u.id = o.id 
  where u.username = 'A'
  group by o.order_date
) t on t.order_date = d.order_date
order by d.order_date
```

Result:

```
 order_date  username  orders 
 ----------- --------- ------ 
 2019-01-01  A         1      
 2019-01-02  A         0      
 2019-01-03  A         1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e2157f7343d1a34731010948f89ef5c).

Comment: In question, we have 2 different table Orders and Users

Comment: @MohammedSalmanNalma:  Luckily the name from the table `Order` is change into `Orders` in this query (which is a good thing, because `ORDER` is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL, and should not be used as a table name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query below in which *includeAllUsers* (using CROSS JOIN) allows you to include **'A'** --*without put it in the SELECT clause*--, and *StrictMatching* gives you the real dataset using matching ID between the two tables Order & Users (by the way, I really recommend you to change the name of your *order* table in Orders or other words, because ORDER is a ***reserved word***).

```
select includeAllUsers.Order_Date, 
       coalesce(StrictMatching.username,includeAllUsers.username) User_Name,
       count(distinct StrictMatching.username) Total_Orders  
from (select o.order_date, u.username, u.id from orders o cross join users u) includeAllUsers 
left join (select o.order_date, u.username,o.id from orders o join users u on o.id=u.id) StrictMatching 
on includeAllUsers.order_date = StrictMatching.order_date and StrictMatching.username='A'
where includeAllUsers.username='A'
group by 
includeAllUsers.order_date, StrictMatching.username, includeAllUsers.username;
```

By combining *includeAllUsers* and *StrictMatching* and filtering by StrictMatching.username='A' (in the criterium of the JOIN clause) et again by includeAllUsers.username='A' (in WHERE clause), you get the correct result.

[Here is a link to verify](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=946409da6e039c264cfb56cbe4190d54)

Comment: He doesn't "have" to change order, its acceptable when wrapped in ``. But I'd agree that ideally he should avoid using reserved words for table names (and columns).

Comment: Yes, I was a bit "severe" :)  As you said : he should avoid using reserved words for table names (and columns). 
Our role is to give limpid and fluid solutions, and optimal if we can do it. The same goes for the suggestions and advice we recommend. So, I'll change "you have to" in my answer.